# Why do "printf scanf" is slower than "cout cin" in this case?

Tags: c++

I have tried to finish a UVa Question: 11559 - Event Planning. However, I have found something that confused me. I have written a code using printf and scanf as IO, but I got a "time limit exceed" in the judge. And I changed my code using cin and cout, then I got a "accepted". Isn't cin or cout slower than scanf and printf ? Here are my code.

"stdio.h" version

```
#define inf 500000000

using namespace std;

int N, B, H, W;
int main ()
{
    while(scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &B, &H, &W)){
        int cost = inf;
        for(int i = 0; i < H; i++){
            int P, k ;
            scanf("%d",&P);
            for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){
                scanf("%d",&k);
                if(k >= N && N*P < cost) cost = N*P;
            }
        }
        if(cost <= B) printf("%d\n",cost);
        else{
            printf("stay home\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

"iostream" version

```
#define inf 500000000

using namespace std;

int N, B, H, W;
int main ()
{
    while(!cin.eof()){
        int cost = inf;
        cin >> N >> B >> H >> W;
        if(cin.eof()) break;
        for(int i = 0; i < H; i++){
            int P, k ;
            cin >> P;
            for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){
                cin >> k;
                if(k >= N && N*P < cost) cost = N*P;
            }
        }
        if(cost <= B) cout << cost << endl;
        else{
            cout << "stay home" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you use `cin.eof()` in the first version like that?

Comment: Are those results repeatable? What was the time difference? There is a slight chance both were on the border.

Comment: You're really (*really*) not supposed to mix streams and C-style I/O.

Comment: how did you measure the execution time? how did you pass in the input?

Comment: I am so sorry that I got a little mistake. "scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &B, &H, &W);" in iostream version should be "cin >> N >> B >> H >> W".

Comment: I am tried so many time in the online judge. It gave the same results.

Comment: The "stdio.h" version exceeds the time limit which is 1 sec. But the "iostream" version can give 0.022sec runtime. I think there is a great difference.

Comment: @unwind Why not? scanf is faster than stringstream. So long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Kit, yes. You should also use edit option more often =)

Comment: @NeilKirk Technically, that depends on the implementation (although in practice, you're probably right for most implementations).  But "knowing what you are doing" with `scanf` is tricky; it's a function that I would _not_ recommend if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: And as I point out in my answser: the `stdio` version has an endless loop; it would exceed the time limit even if the time limit were a hundred years.  (Why the poster didn't actually run the program on his own machine, and notice this, is beyond me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `cin` and `cout` aren't significantly different from using `printf`/`scanf`. However, `endl` will call `ofstream::flush()`, which would be the same thing as `printf("%d\n", cost); fflush(stdout);`, and I expect if you did that, it would run slower there too.

Also, mixing `cin` with `scanf` or similar will add more time, because the code has to "sync" the two I/O streams all the time. I would suggest you rewrite your `scanf` input as:

```
while(scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &B, &H, &W) != EOF){
    int cost = inf;
    // remove scanf and cin.eof() line here
    ...
}
```

To prove my point about (at least output):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    unsigned long long t = rdtsc();
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            cout << i << "\n";
        }

    }

    t = rdtsc() - t; 
    cerr << "Time: " << t << endl;
}
```

The output from this, when running with no arguments (`argc == 1`) and running with an argument (`argc == 2`) is:

```
$ ./a.out > foo.txt
Time: 1672894
$ ./a.out 1 > foo.txt
Time: 1513620
```

Approximately 10% difference in favour of `printf`. However, there is quite a bit of variation in my system when I run any benchmark, so that should be taken with a pinch of salt. Note that using `endl` instead of `"/n"` makes a significant difference!

For `cin` vs. `scanf`, there is a little more difference to the disadvantage of `scanf`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    unsigned long long t = rdtsc();
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int tmp;
            scanf("%d", &tmp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int tmp;
            cin >> tmp;
        }

    }

    t = rdtsc() - t; 
    cerr << "Time: " << t << endl;
}


$ ./a.out < foo.txt
Time: 1990454
$ ./a.out 1 < foo.txt
Time: 4804226
```

As you can see, `scanf` is nearly 2.5 times slower... However, I have seen other cases where it's not such a big difference. I'm not entirely sure why there is such a big difference here.

In summary, there are difference, but I do believe the answer by James Kanze is closer to explaining what is going on - the code simply fails to complete because `cin.eof()` does not get set by `scanf`.

Comment: Did you read that the `printf/scanf` version was already slower, even though he uses `endl`.

Comment: @luk32: Yes, see the second comment.

Comment: Your 1st answer skipped that, missing the question. But still, he mixes it in both versions. 1st uses only `cin.eof()` though, but 2nd mixes `operator>>/operator<<` with `scanf`. By your logic it should run slower or the same. OP results say otherwise! You explain why the 2nd version should be slower... this is easy. Please explain why OP sees it is actually faster. Their results are against your answer, that's why I think its not a good one. At least yet.

Comment: Mixing in EITHER direction will potentially slow things down. The exact details of will depend on the exact implementation. Keeping it to one side or the other will result in much better results. It's worth noting that BOTH variants does quite a bit of mixing, so it's hard to say exactly what is faster and what is slower, without measuring [and me measuring on my system will not necessarily give the same result as some other system - I have no idea what the system is that this runs on].

Comment: If you're going with `scanf`, it's better to use `== 4` than `!= EOF` as that will catch cases where only some variables were read, or there was non-numeric input.

Comment: @interjay: True. However, as this is for one of those online judging contests, it tends to be that they don't give "bad input" - that's not part of the code.

Comment: I have tried to replace all `cin cout` of my `stdio.h` version of code . But it also failed.

Comment: I'm not sure mixing will slow things down.  It does more or less guarantee that you won't get the right results, however.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I believe there is, in most implementations, a calls to `sync_with_stdio` or some such at "strategic" places in a typical implementation. But either way, keeping it to one or the other is definitely a good plan.

Comment: The C++ standard requires `sync_with_stdio` to be true at program start up.  But what this means isn't too clear; I've always understood it to mean that the buffers were synchronized.  (But how can use synchronize the buffers of `stdin` and `std::cin`?)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: `while(scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &B, &H, &W)){` will probably continue forever, unless you have invalid input - because you reach EOF, `scanf` returns `EOF`, which is `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is certain: `scanf` has no effect on `std::cin.eof()`.
So your first code has an endless loop.  The second code
actually reads something from `std::cin`, and will eventually
cause `std::cin.eof()` to return true.

Both codes, however, have numerous other problems.  Given your
level, you should forget about `scanf`; it's far to dangerous
and complex.  Use `std::cin` everywhere.  And check that it
succeeds *after* the input, but before using the results
(always).  (`std::cin.eof()` does *not* tell you whether the
previous input succeeded, nor whether the next will succeed or
fail.  Until you know that the previous input has failed, it's
use is probably an error.)

The idiomatic way of writing your code would involve something
like:

```
while ( std::cin >> N >> B >> H >> W ) ...
```

(Except that no experienced C++ programmer would use global
variables for them; nor, for that matter, a single capital
letter as the name.)  The other inputs should be handled
similarly.

Comment: I can bet this question comes from more algorithmic background than "proper" production code. These often do not need to be good reusable codes, just short clean and easy to read. This is also partially the reason behind skipping checks. You can usually safely assume that the input is correct, so not many people bother checking it. I am not excusing, this approach poured some bad habits into me, just explaning. One thing however bothers me. I also thought there is an endless loop, but why does it end and is "accepted" then?

Comment: Does the "scanf has no effect on std::cin.eof()" depend on the actual implementation - not saying this isn't true for MOST implementations, just that theoretcially, one could implement just about all of iostream using `stdin` and `stdout`, and if `cin.eof()` actually returns the same as `feof(stdin)`, then it would...

Comment: @luk32: First example ISN'T being accepted, because it doesn't reach `cin.eof()` being true ever - however, in the second case `cin >> ...` will (one would assume) eventually reach an end-of-file situation, even if that also means some random garbage was being given for the previous values.

Comment: Aw I think I got it. 1st code probably works good too, but gets killed after the time limit by the checker. That's why 2ns is faster. Duh, I'm stupid, but maybe its worth checking and writing explicitly. @Mats yes, probably the truth is 1st code is not actually slower. It is never ending. Properly written would be slightly faster due to `endl` flush, as you have suggested.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think it's guaranteed by the standard, although I know that the original intent was that `scanf` could use `>>` under the hood.  We're back to a point which came up in another discussion: a function cannot change observable state (like `std::cin.eof()`) unless it is documented to do so.  And the documentation of `scanf` makes no mention of anything in iostream.  Rather obviously, since it is in the C standard.  (The C++ standard could, and probably should add words documentation a difference here, to allow it.  But it doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I know the answer is out there, but I still do not see a clear and clean explanation why does the OP observe. So, getting best out of James' and Mats' answers i'll try to get a nice easy to understand explanation.

The thing is the 1st code does not run slower *per-se*. As James' say, there is a probable infinite loop.

**Why does the 1st code seem to run slower?** Because of an endless loop, the automatic judge kills it after the time limit. The algorithm and I/O is not slower.

Given your time differences: 0.022s to 1s. There is no way (in practice) there could be such a big difference due to I/O implementation differences between c and c++.

I have no input example. But my bet is if you take suggestion from Mats' answer, and use following code, 1st code will work properly and give same time results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define inf 500000000
int N, B, H, W;
int main ()
{
    while(scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &B, &H, &W) != EOF){ //Mats' suggestion
        int cost = inf;
        //if(cin.eof()) break; //not needed `while` checks it
        for(int i = 0; i < H; i++){
            int P, k ;
            scanf("%d",&P);
            for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){
                scanf("%d",&k);
                if(k >= N && N*P < cost) cost = N*P;
            }
        }
        if(cost <= B) printf("%d",cost);
        else{
            printf("stay home\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you post is still largely incorrect.  Like `istream`, an input `FILE*` _must_ be checked before using any of the values it has input.  It's just a lot more difficult to check.  (For example, your `while` should be `while ( scanf(...) == 4 )`; the other `scanf` need to be checked as well.)  The only reasonable answer here is: do all of your input using `std::cin`.  Anything else requires a real expert to get right.

Comment: @James I concur, as I explained in my comment under your answer, and someone else in other comment. This code is not meant as a production-code supposed to interact with users and the **input can be assumed to be correct**. This is also not a problem of the coder, if there is a problem with `stdin` or `stdout`, in this case. In every decent algorithmic competition this is given in the rules. I also dropped the `using namespace std` and included headers to make it clear that this is `c` code.